# Visual Studio 2015 glclear not found in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have some problem With OpenGL
I wrote this code in Visual Studio 2015, but when I compile it visual Studio showed me errors such as "Too many arguments in function call" and "glClear not found" and "glLookAt function does not take 18 arguments" and...
How do I solve it ?
this is my code:

```
#define glclear
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <glut.h>
void display()
{
    glclear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    glutWireTeapot(2, 0);
    glFlush();
}
void init()
{
    glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0);
    glColor3b(0, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-4, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 4, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv);
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Orthographic Projection");
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Link to opengl32.lib to solve at least one of those errors. The other one is either a typo when you wrote this question or when you wrote the code -- it's `gluLookAt`; it only takes 9 arguments either way though.

Answer (score 2):

- `gluLookAt` does not take 18 arguments, it takes 9 ([doc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)).
- `glClearColor` does also not take 8 arguments, it takes 4 ([doc](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml)).
- `glclear` has a typo. It should be `glClear`. And the error message you posted is most probably not copied correctly.

I'm not sure why you think this code should work or from which source you took your information.

Comment: I'm guessing that he is from a country where the decimal mark is a comma rather than a period, and he has therefore mistakenly transformed all of his periods into commas when he copy-and-pasted that code.